# Qual è il significato di "baldanzoso" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> "Vien buono l'alberello della lacca" pensò Artemisia per darsi animo: ma già l'ha colta quel presentimento insopportabile che a ogni nuovo lavoro d'impegno si ripete: dipingerà, anche questa volta, il solito ritratto **baldanzoso** di cui è così facile gloriarsi, così difficile contentarsi.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "baldanzoso" in questa frase. Ho cercato questo vocabolo nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/baldanzoso/) e ho trovato che significa

> Che ha o mostra baldanza

e cercando il [significato di baldanza](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/baldanza/) ho trovato

> Grande (e talvolta eccessiva) fiducia nelle proprie forze, nella sorte: *b. giovanile; pigliare b.; togliere b.; Li occhi a la terra e le ciglia avea rase D’ogne b.* (Dante); talora anche presunzione o spavalderia: *parlare con troppa baldanza*.

Tuttavia, non capisco cos'è un "ritratto baldanzoso". Significa che il ritratto mostra che la pittrice ha fiducia nelle sua capacità per fare quel lavoro? Vuol dire che la persona ritratta è quella che mostra baldanza, cioè, fiducia nella propria sorte? Significa un ritratto presuntuoso?

Comment: "Persona ritratta". "Ritrattata" si dice, ad esempio, di un'affermazione che viene ritirata perché ci si accorge che è sbagliata o non è adeguata. :-)

Comment: Grazie, @Benedetta, faccio la correzione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondo me con l'aggettivo *baldanzoso* Anna Banti vuole dire il rapporto di Artemisia con la propria arte: la pittrice sente, da una parte, che il suo ritratto sarà ben eseguito ("è facile gloriarsi"), dall'altra, che non ne sarà pienamente soddisfatta ("difficile contentarsi").
L'atteggiamento baldanzoso è l'atteggiamento di qualcuno che ha molta fiducia nelle proprie capacità ma spesso questa fiducia non corrisponde alla realtà. Di solito, chi è baldanzoso, spavaldo, non è consapevole di esserlo, ma Anna Banti vuole dire che Artemisia lo è. Gli artisti non sono mai soddisfatti delle loro opere: anche quando la tecnica e l'esperienza li aiuta a fare qualcosa di bello, sentono che possono fare ancora meglio.

*Baldanzoso* non significa semplicemente che una persona ha fiducia nelle proprie capacità, ma che questa fiducia è eccessiva, cioè che le sue capacità non sono così grandi. Di solito, una persona spavalda non pensa di esserlo, sono gli altri a giudicarlo così. In questo caso, Anna Banti vuole dire che Artemisia riconosce che il ritratto che farà avrà la presunzione di essere un grande ritratto, ma in realtà non sarà poi così bello.

Comment: Potresti spiegarlo un po' di più? Non capisco la relazione della tua risposta con la definizione di "baldanzoso" che ho trovato.

Comment: L'atteggiamento baldanzoso è l'atteggiamento di qualcuno che ha molta fiducia nelle proprie capacità ma spesso questa fiducia non corrisponde alla realtà. Di solito, chi è baldanzoso, spavaldo, non è consapevole di esserlo, ma Anna Banti vuole dire che Artemisia lo è. Gli artisti non sono mai soddisfatti delle loro opere: anche quando la tecnica e l'esperienza li aiuta a fare qualcosa di bello, sentono che posso fare ancora meglio.

Comment: Ma non è contraddittorio? Cioè, se Artemisia ha un atteggiamento baldanzoso significa che ha molta fiducia nelle sue capacità, ma la frase spiega che ha un presentimento insopportabile prima di cominciare il lavoro e che sente che sia difficile contentarsi di questo "ritratto baldanzoso".

Comment: Non è contraddittorio, perché "baldanzoso" non significa semplicemente che una persona ha fiducia nelle proprie capacità, ma che questa fiducia è eccessiva, cioè che le sue capacità non sono così grandi. Di solito, una persona spavalda non pensa di esserlo, sono gli altri a giudicarlo così. In questo caso, Anna Banti vuole dire che Artemisia riconosce che il ritratto che farà avrà la presunzione di essere un grande ritratto, ma in realtà non sarà poi così bello.

Comment: Quindi, gli altri giudicheranno il ritratto come fatto da una persona baldanzosa, quando la pittrice pensa che poi non sarà tanto buono. È così?

Comment: Potresti aggiungere il contenuto dei tuoi commenti al testo della risposta? Penso che così si capisca meglio.

Comment: Le persone lo giudicheranno bello (Artemisia se ne potrà gloriare), ma la pittrice saprà che avrebbe potuto essere migliore (sarà difficile contentarsi).

Comment: @Charo: ho aggiunto alla risposta i commenti. Pensi che così sia più chiaro?

Comment: Sì, grazie, così è chiaro.